# How to calculate seconds from now to exact datetime?

Tags: c#, datetime

I want to calculate the seconds from now to another datetime for example tomorrow 8:00 am. I couldn't find anything (or I didn't use good keywords - and I don't know another one!)

Can anybody help me?

Comment: @Oded I don't know a lot about datetime. so I couldn't try anything. I want a solution!

Comment: Did you try reading the documentation, to see what's available?

Comment: «I want a solution!» ... sounds more like you want someone else to do the dirty work for you.

Comment: @IvarBonsaksen I just couldn't find any solution and I've got an exception with `DateTime s = dateTimePicker1.Value - DateTime.Now;` now I know that I have to use `TimeSpan` instead of `DateTime`!

Comment: This last comment of yours should show you _why_ you should include code examples, in particular if you are getting compile errors!

Comment: `-1 ahmadali shafiee` "Can't find" is not an acceptable excuse the internet has thousands of awesome `DateTime` Example [Awesome C# Examples can be found right here from your PC](http://www.google.com)

Comment: @Oded I thought the datetime doesn't has `-` operator so I didn't think that the code is necessary! but yes you are right!

Comment: @DJKRAZE My name is `ahmadali shafiee`! I know that but I didn't know where to start

Comment: The subtraction operator has been [implemented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1905yhe2.aspx) for `DateTime`.

Comment: The answer is right in front of you ..you need to dig deep into the Class.. something may pop right out in front of you.. other require further digging

Comment: Side note: It is so sad to learn that all efforts put into providing contextual help (click on DateTime in VS and press F1) and intellisense in Visual Studio are getting so little use.

Comment: `Alexei Levenkov` I totally agree but what's sad is the fact that how lazy some of these `so called I wanna be a programmer type guys` have the utmost sense of laziness .. totally amazing on `SO`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
TimeSpan t = YourDateTime - DateTime.Now;
t.TotalSeconds; //is what you're looking for
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var tomorrow8AM = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(1).AddHours(8);
var difference = tomorrow8AM - myDateTime;
var inSeconds = different.TotalSeconds;
```

I do suggest you read the MSDN documentation for [`DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03ybds8y.aspx) and [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx).

Comment: so I've tried `DateTime s = dateTimePicker1.Value - DateTime.Now;` and I've got an exception!

Comment: @ahmadalishafiee - As expected. The result of subtracting `DateTime`s from each other is not a `DateTime`. It is a `TimeSpan`.

Comment: Oh my..I think the OP really needs to read about how to use `DateTime`and `TimeSpan` especially in regards to doing calculations on Duration and things of that nature.. it's not the same a subtracting real number btw `Ahmadali`

Comment: Totally agree, @DJ. People should spend more time reading the existing documentation before asking questions.

Comment: `+1 Oded` long time no talk.. I totally agree with that statement.. I am so tired of people wanting the quick answer opposed to to just reading and or trying something first .. it will catch up to them in the long run especially when it comes to `supporting and or Bug fixes and Refactoring request` LOL

Answer (score 1):

Ahmadali Shafiee here is a nice method I wrote for you that you can use anytime you need you can extend it anyway you like but reading this might give you a better idea of how you can use this Method to return TimeSpan

```
public static TimeSpan GetTimeSpan(DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime)
{
    TimeSpan totTime = new TimeSpan();
    startTime = Convert.ToDateTime(startTime.TimeOfDay.ToString());
    endTime = Convert.ToDateTime(endTime.TimeOfDay.ToString());
    totTime = (TimeSpan)(endTime - startTime);
    return totTime;
    // or you can return totTime.TotalSeconds
}
```

if you want to return the Total seconds you can also alter the return portion or you can overload this method and pass in a few extra variables to return Total Hours, Total Minutes, Total Seconds as well as Total Milliseconds feel free to mess around with this code.

Comment: For what its worth... +1

Comment: Thanks Bas.. I appreciate the vote of confidence :)